# ReactiveUI WhenAnyValue ToPropertyEx to a nullable decimal

Tags: c#, reactiveui

Using a nullable decimal as a variable, `[Reactive] public decimal? CustomPrice { get; set; }`, I am trying to update it with the following:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.DiscountPercent, x => x.DiscountFlat, x=>x.UnitPriceOriginal,
   (percent, flat, orig) => ((percent > 0) || (flat > 0)) ? orig * percent - flat : (decimal?)null)
   .ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.CustomPrice);
```

`DiscountPercent DiscountFlat UnitPriceOriginal` are all decimal variables. `DiscountPercent DiscountFlat` are set from the database or from user input fields. `CustomPrice` is editable from a user input field as well, which has been working to update `CustomPrice`. `CustomPrice` is then used to set the decimal value `UnitPrice` using:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CustomPrice, x => x.UnitPriceOriginal,
   (custom, orig) => custom ?? orig)
   .ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.UnitPrice);
```

I need the `CustomPrice` to be updated when values are entered into `DiscountPercent` and/or `DiscountFlat` otherwise it needs to be `null` which then sets the `UnitPrice` to the `UnitPriceOriginal`. With the first block of code I get a runtime error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type ObservableAsPropertyHelper`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]'.'

I have tried many different ways to work around this, but when updating a nullable variable I run into errors. Is there a different way I can set a nullable decimal as an Observable during runtime? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Declaring the property without ReactiveUI.Fody attributes should make the code snippet work as expected, so worth trying to remove `[Reactive]` and to declare this particular property as shown here https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-models/#read-write-properties E.g. the `[Reactive]` attribute currently doesn't seem to fully support the new nullability annotations (the work is in progress)

Comment: @Artyom I wish it was that simple. Tried that. Different error: >System.Exception: 'Backing field not found for System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal] CustomPrice'

Comment: According to https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/search?q=Backing+field+not+found the exception seems to be coming from ReactiveUI.Fody so looks like it attempts to generate some stuff anyway. Make sure you remove that `[Reactive]` attribute to prevent that... If you implement a property with `RaiseAndSetIfChanged` then you don't need Fody as you are doing manually what Fody *should* do.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that in the project in which you are using the `Reactive` and `ObservableAsProperty` attributes you have a ***direct*** reference to the [`ReactiveUI.Fody`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReactiveUI.Fody/) package; it cannot be implicitly referenced through another project. Without this direct reference, the `FodyWeavers.xml` file is not created and you will get strange behaviors from your reactive properties.

Comment: Straight to the point! Thanks!